# Google Analytics on dynamic iFramed content with multiple parent domain solutions?

Tags: javascript, iframe, coldfusion, google-analytics, web-analytics

First of all I've searched all over the Internet for advice and solutions, I built a test case based on [this blog post](http://www.emarketeur.fr/gestion-de-projet/developper/mesurer-son-trafic-sur-plusieurs-domaines-au-travers-dun-iframe-avec-google-analytics). The problem is the real world website/setup is a lot more involved than a static test page with a static test iFramed content.

I can put the Google Analytics tracking javascript in the header, but I need to dynamically choose which analytic tracking code to use.

There is good news, the parent page is owned by 'us' and the dynamic content will reach out and pull a header from 'us' which they will then prepend to the dynamic content. The header can even be a ColdFusion (.cfm) file, the problem is the ColdFusion is evaluated before it is sent to the 3rd Party. It gets worse as the 3rd Party is doing redirects and uses multiple subdomains to serve up the dynamic content.

Previously on the ColdFusion extranet website ColdFusion was used to check server variables to determine which Google Analytic tracking code to use. In my testing this isn't an option as due to how the header is fetched and the fact the header sits on the same server regardless of where it is fetched from, we don't get useful data from ColdFusion.

JavaScript can also be used to check host, domain, referer and alas all the redirects and iFrames are making that problematic. Here is what I've tried in the 'header' to figure out what data I can use to determine which analytic tracking code to use:

```
  <!--- Debugging code --->
  console.log('testing testing testing');
  var isInIframe = (parent !== window);

  if (isInIframe) 
  {
    parentUrl = document.referrer;
    console.log('JS parentURL ' + parentUrl);
    console.log('JS document.domain ' + document.domain);
    console.log('JS window.location.hostname ' + window.location.hostname);
    console.log('JS window.parent.domain ' + window.parent.domain);
    console.log('JS window.frameElement ' + window.frameElement);
  }
  else
  {   
    console.log('Not in iFrame according to JS test');
  }

  console.log('CF HTTP_REFERER ' + '<cfoutput>#CGI.HTTP_REFERER#</cfoutput>'); <!--- always blank --->
  console.log('CF HTTP_HOST ' + '<cfoutput>#CGI.HTTP_HOST#</cfoutput>'); 
  console.log('CF SERVER_NAME ' + '<cfoutput>#CGI.SERVER_NAME#</cfoutput>');
  console.log('CF REMOTE_HOST ' + '<cfoutput>#CGI.REMOTE_HOST#</cfoutput>');
  console.log('Done testing');
</script>
```

There are 3 main cases we want to track with seperate Google Analytic tracking codes ie UA-XXXXXXXX-1, UA-XXXXXXXX-2, UA-XXXXXXXX-3, these are on three different domains, but there is only one header.cfm file. I can tell the difference between the extranet and the internet using either document.domain or window.location.hostname, because the dynamic content comes from different sources, but I'm less sure I can tell the difference between two different Internet websites. The dynamic content differentiates between B2C and B2B usage, so multiple B2C Internet websites are served the same data. The extranet site always gets the B2B data. The B2C is on subdomain1.host.com and B2B is on subdomain2.host.com.

Is there a good way to do this with JavaScript? Should we be appending an argument in a URL? I've even though of using a meta tag or hidden form field to pass info... I'd prefer to have the JavaScript in the header figure this out based on referer/host, but I'm not sure it can due to all the redirects and dynamic iFramed content. document.referrer always comes back the same blah.blah/continue.asp

Comment: I tried a bunch more JavaScript DOM paths and some more ColdFusion CGI variables. It is dissappointing the HTTP Request Referer is being lost along the way, fixing that would solve all my problems. I also found Query_String CGI variable has data, if I can get the third party vendor to let us pass say our UA-XXXXXXXXX-1 code as an argument which they ignore but we pull and plug into the JavaScript header, I could also get the functionality desired.